# Loading a WPF form into a MFC application without /clr

Tags: wpf, mfc, hosting, unmanaged, managed

I am trying to integrate WPF into a legacy MFC application.  I am unable to include the /clr switch to mix managed and unmanaged due to the restrictions of other projects in the solution.  I need the WPF window open up as a child window in the main MFC application.  I have been investigating different ways for the past two weeks but have hit roadblock with every implementation try.  If anyone has successfully integrated this type of implementation, I would appreciate some direction.  I have been able to integrate with a Win32 app, but could not translate this to an MFC app.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: how did you get it to work with Win32?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that WPF requires .NET, therefore what you need is to create a separate DLL or EXE for the WPF parts.  hat new project could be the container for .NET code and your main MFC would launch this separate project.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a WPF front end that launches C++ apps with the desired command like switches, similar to what Visual Studio 2010 is doing to compile your code and show the results in the output pane. In this way you can avoid having to hack message loop code to support both frameworks .

Answer (score 0):

You may show your Dialog using a COM interface